# SwiftUI Firebase. Deletes all Items not just one

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to delete an item with its Id (`let db = Firestore.firestore()` `db.collection("Warenkorb").document(i.id).delete()`). So this is my code. Sadly when I'm deleting one item all items in the collection get deleted as well. Why? Can someone help me?

```
ForEach(cart.data) { i in
     HStack{
         Image("pic").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 50, height: 75, alignment: .leading).padding().foregroundColor(.black)
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(i.name).font(.system(size: 25)).foregroundColor(.black)
                HStack{
                Text(i.preis).font(.system(size: 20)).foregroundColor(.black)
              Text(i.size).font(.system(size: 20)).foregroundColor(.black)
                }
         }
       Spacer()
        Text("\(i.quantity)").font(.system(size: 25)).foregroundColor(.black)
       Spacer()
                       if self.remove{

        Button(action: {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("Warenkorb").document(i.id).delete()
            self.show.toggle()
            self.show.toggle()


                                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

            }
                        }
        Spacer()

     }
     .background(Color("Color-1")).frame(width: 350, height:  100).cornerRadius(30).padding(.leading)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add data access code in your SwiftUI views. Instead, implement a view model (and, optionally, a repository) to manage your data.

I've adapted your code a bit:

**View**

```swift
struct ShoppingCartView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ShoppingCartViewModel

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.lineItems) { lineItem in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(lineItem.title)
            .font(.headline)
        }
      }
      .onDelete { indexSet in
        self.viewModel.deleteLineItems(at: indexSet)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**View Model**

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Combine

class ShoppingCartViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var lineItems = [LineItem]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?

  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    fetchData()
  }

  deinit {
    unregister()
  }

  func unregister() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
    }
  }

  func fetchData() {
    unregister()

    listenerRegistration = db.collection("shoppingCart").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.lineItems = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> LineItem? in
        let lineItem = try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: LineItem.self)
        return lineItem
      }
    }
  }

  func deleteLineItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    let itemsToDelete = offsets.lazy.map { self.lineItems[$0] }
    itemsToDelete.forEach { lineItem in
      if let id = lineItem.id {
        db.collection("shoppingCart").document(id).delete()
      }
    }
  }
}
```